# Clicking on an item in a list opens a Google Maps marker asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to make a google map and a list of positions that I have in my SQL database.

When I click on an item in the list it opens a Google Maps marker in the map. I use Visual Sstudio 2015 ASP.Net with c# and JQuery.

This is my Google Map in *** *.aspx***:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="GMaps" Namespace="Subgurim.Controles" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h3> Google Map</h3>
    <div>
        <cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" Width="800px" Height=" 500px"/> 
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is the code in the *** *.aspx.cs***:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GMap1.setCenter(new Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(24.0, 75.0), 5);
            GLatLng GLatLong = new GLatLng(50.5, 12.81);
            GMarker gMarker = new GMarker(GLatLong);
            GMap1.Add(gMarker);
            GMap1.setCenter(GLatLong, 9, GMapType.GTypes.Normal);
            List<Location> location = new List<Location>(); 
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities()) 
            {
                location = dc.Location.Where(a => a.Name.Equals("408701")).ToList(); 
            }
```